# How to locate a list of elements with @FindBy

Tags: selenium, fluentlenium

While working with Pages in FluentLenium @FindBy can be used to locate a FluentWebElement:

```
@FindBy(id = "one")
FluentWebElement exactlyOne;
```

This works perfectly fine. But now I need to locate multiple elements:

```
@FindBy(tagName = "p")
List<FluentWebElement> allP;
```

I cannot make this to work. I tried declaring the field as: List, FluentList even List but I always get null.

I am using: Selenium: 2.46.0, FluentLenium: 0.10.3

Answer (score 0):

I checked the source code and it seems like with (unreleased yet) version 0.10.4 it is fixed.

```
@FindBy(className = "small")
FluentList<FluentWebElement> smalls;
```

Details of the commit: https://github.com/FluentLenium/FluentLenium/commit/2e22e244caa0b4b178ec72ceddd8680c6fbe4c46